# Working with cronjobs

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I am venturing into the world of setting up cronjobs and trying to learn more about the server side of things. In doing so, I have attempted to setup a Cronjob on my server to run two separate Ruby scripts on two separate days.

**The Problem:**
I setup a cronjob to run at noon on Feb 8, 2011 on the 2nd day of the week (Tuesday), but it ran today instead of the 8th.

**Cronjobs**

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
00 12 5 2 6 /usr/local/bin/ruby /home/ubuntu/email_f.rb
00 12 8 2 2 /usr/local/bin/ruby /home/ubuntu/email_g.rb
```

Am I doing something wrong? The second script is the one that should run on Feb 8, which is next Tuesday, but like I said, it ran today instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have an ubuntu box handy, but the man file on my slackware box says:

*If you specify both a day in the month and a day of week, the result is  effectively  ORd... the crontab entry will be run on the specified day of week and on the specified day in the month.*

The Vixie cron on fedora agrees:

*Note: The day of a command’s execution can be specified by two fields — day  of  month,  and  day  of week.  If both fields are restricted (ie, aren’t *), the command will be run when either field matches  the  current time.  For example, "30  4  1,15 * 5" would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus every Friday.*

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of senese now! I am changing my cronjob to specify a * in the day of the week so that it will run only on the day of the month specified.